# Barred and unbarred systems

Tags: differential-geometry

Say I have the set of linear equations 
$\bar x = 5x-2y$ and 
$\bar y= 3x+2y$

which define a linear transformation.

The image of the point $(0,-1)$ is $(2,-2)$

Similarly $(2,1)$  has the image $(8,8)$.

If we have two fixed points $p$ and $q$ why do they have the respective coordinates $(0,-1)$ and $(2,1)$ in the unbarred system and $(2,-2)$ and $(8,8)$ in the barred system?

What does unbarred and barred mean in this context?

Comment: Instead of a linear transformation, what this equations set is a coordinates' change

Answer (score 0):

Unbarred and barred basically means the old and new system respectively here. The name unbarred comes from the bar over the $\bar x$ and $\bar y$.